# Merge two sorted arrays and the resulting array should also be sorted

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Let's say you have two arrays of arrays with the same structure but different count of arrays in them:

```
$arr1 = array(array(1,"b"), array(2,"a"), array(5,"c"));  
$arr2 = array(array(3,"e"));
```

Now, the data in the $arr1 and $arr2 is sorted, and now what I would like it to merge these two arrays, so I did this:

```
$res = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
```

And then I get an output like this:

```
1-b  
2-a
5-c  
3-e
```

But, I would like to have a sorted $res also like this:

```
1-b  
2-a
3-e  
5-c
```

I wonder if there's a function in PHP to do this automatically, without me having to write my own function? Or, please advise me on which is the best approach for this if I want to (later on) add sorting by the next parameter so the output would be like this

```
2-a  
1-b
5-c  
3-e
```

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: You will need to resort after the merge, it should only be one extra line of code to call your sort routine

Comment: Don't mean to be rude, but I know what I had to do, just didn't know how, which was my question in the first place. So, sorry but you didn't help at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first merge the arrays and then sort the final array.

You are probably looking for a multi-sort function. I usually use this function (I found this functions somewhere on the internet years ago, credits go to the original author):

```
/*
 * sort a multi demensional array on a column
 *
 * @param array $array array with hash array
 * @param mixed $column key that you want to sort on
 * @param enum $order asc or desc
 */
function array_qsort2 (&$array, $column=0, $order="ASC") {
    $oper = ($order == "ASC")?">":"<";
    if(!is_array($array)) return;
    usort($array, create_function('$a,$b',"return (\$a['$column'] $oper \$b['$column']);")); 
    reset($array);
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
array_qsort2($res, 0, "ASC");
```

Comment: However sorting after merge makes this an O(n log n) solution, where a proper merge(like what's used by merge sort) is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply call [`ksort($res)`](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) after your array_merge?

Comment: Don't know if I'm doing sth wrong, but I couldn't get it working with ksort(). I get the same array as after the merge. fiegs answer was exactly what I needed. Thx for reply though.

Comment: This is performance-ignorant solution. Of course it's fine for any short arrays. But what OP is asking about usually is intended to run with O(n) time, where n is the sum of array lengths.

Comment: just because you don't need to sort as data is pre-sorted. proper merge will be O(NM). array_merge + sort will be O(NM log(NM))

Answer (score 1):

Since `php v5.3` you can use anon functions in a more natural manner,

```
<?php

$arr1 = array(array(1,"b"), array(2,"a"), array(5,"c"));  
$arr2 = array(array(3,"e"));  


$res = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);  

usort($res, function($a,$b) {
  // php7
  // return $a[0] <=> $b[0];

  if ($a[0] == $b[0]) return 0; 
  return $a[0] < $b[0] ? -1 : 1;
});

print_r($res);
```

output

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => b
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => a
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => e
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => c
    )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function to merge two sorted arrays without array_merge() or sort().

```
 <?php



$arr1 = [1,2,5,7,10,20,36,70,82,90];
$arr2 = [4,6,10,15,65,85,90,100];

function shortt($array1,$array2){



 $array1_count = count($array1);
   $array2_count = count($array2);

while ($array1_count || $array2_count)
{
  $array1_empty = $array1 == [];
  $array2_empty = $array2 == [];

if (!$array1_empty && !$array2_empty)
{
    if (current($array1) < current($array2))
    {
        $array3[] = array_shift($array1);
        $array1_count--;
    }
    else
    {
        $array3[] = array_shift($array2);
        $array2_count--;
    }
}
elseif (!$array1_empty)
{
    $array3[] = array_shift($array1);
    $array1_count--;
}
elseif (!$array2_empty)
{
    $array3[] = array_shift($array2);
    $array2_count--;


  }


    }

         return $array3;      
 }


$newarr = shortt($arr1,$arr2);

print_r($newarr); 


?>
```